# Button moving when font is inputted

Tags: css

I have 9 buttons lined up for a tic tac toe board. If I add an X or O as the text for any of the buttons the entire button moves up in firefox and down in chrome/safari. Any ideas why? Seems like an easy one but I've spent quite a while trying to fix it.

An example https://jsfiddle.net/fo4vyd24/

```css
/*//////////////////////////////////////
     UNIVERSAL
    //////////////////////////////////////*/

* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-decoration: none;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}
img,
video {
  max-width: 100%;
}
input,
button,
select,
submit {
  border: none;
}
/*//////////////////////////////////////
     TIC TAC TOE
    //////////////////////////////////////*/

.players,
.ttt-board,
.scoreboard {
  width: 33%;
  float: left;
}
.btn {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px rgba(122, 122, 122, 1);
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px rgba(122, 122, 122, 1);
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 4px 4px rgba(122, 122, 122, 1);
}
.x,
.o {
  font-size: 64px;
}
```

```html
<div class="ttt-board">
  <section class="top-row">
    <button class="tp-left btn" value=" "></button>
    <button class="tp-mid btn" value=" "></button>
    <button class="tp-right btn" value=" "></button>
  </section>

  <section class="mid-row">
    <button class="md-left btn" value=" "><span class="x">x</span>
    </button>
    <button class="md-mid btn" value=" "><span class="o">o</span>
    </button>
    <button class="md-right btn" value=" "></button>
  </section>

  <section class="bottom-row">
    <button class="bm-left btn" value=" "></button>
    <button class="bm-mid btn" value=" "></button>
    <button class="bm-right btn" value=" "></button>
  </section>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you provide a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Comment: 80px width for a 64px font? Set font-size for .btn and apply width (and height) to, let's say, 1.5em

Comment: A bigger size still causes the buttons to shift. The font size even at a smaller size still causes shift, it just increases the bigger the size.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try the following in the .x,.o class

```
position:absolute;
transform: translateX(-50%);
```

Here is a [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nxa6qsct/3/) to see it working.

Comment: Actually that worked fine. Thanks! I usually go with absolute positioning when in a pinch.

Comment: Actually it still doesn't work for ios safari which is weird since -webkit- fix should work.